# Is it possible to draw a broken axis graph with seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, seaborn

I need to draw a broken x axis graph (e.g. the graph below) with existing data, my question is whether it's possible to use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) APIs to do that?

[image]

Comment: Yes, look here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html

Comment: Does this work for seaborn as well? It looks like seaborn plot generates the plot object itself, and I can replace the matplotlib object generated here:
`f, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)`

Comment: As seaborn is completely built on top of matplotlib it will surely work. The details depend on your implementation.

Comment: The answer given here worked nicely for me and includes the use of seaborn: https://gist.github.com/pfandzelter/0ae861f0dee1fb4fd1d11344e3f85c9e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as pretty as I'd like but works.

[image: Output]

```
%matplotlib inline  # If you are running this in a Jupyter Notebook.
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, sharey=True)
ax = sns.tsplot(time=x, data=y, ax=ax1)
ax = sns.tsplot(time=x, data=y, ax=ax2)

ax1.set_xlim(0, 6.5)
ax2.set_xlim(13.5, 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

A tighter version (also replaced the deprecated `tsplot`). Can control the distance between the plots by the `wspace` parameter in the `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)` line.

[image]

```py
%matplotlib inline 
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, sharey=True)
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y, ax=ax1)
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y, ax=ax2)

ax1.set_xlim(0, 6.5)
ax2.set_xlim(13.5, 20)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```